# Why is the measurability condition in the definition of a predictable process the same as "the value at $t$ is know at $t-1$"?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

First of all, here is a related question asked:
[What exactly is a 'predictable process'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190739/what-exactly-is-a-predictable-process)

My question is, why $X_t$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ the same as the value of $X_t$ is known at $t-1$ ?

A similar question can be asked about an adapted process.

Let's focus on discrete processes for the moment.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't need stochastic processes to see this, it is a more basic theorem that if $Y $ is $\sigma (X) $ measurable then there is a Borel function $f $ such that $Y=f(X) $. This should be in any measure theoretic probability book, though not under any particular name.

Comment: @lan This answers the question!